# PHP shell_exec Failed To Execute Hadoop Command

Tags: php, hadoop

First of all I need to tell you guys that this question is actually duplicate in here

[Running php script to execute hadoop command via shell on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456562/running-php-script-to-execute-hadoop-command-via-shell-on-browser)

So I have a same problem (I can't execute any Hadoop command from php) but unfortunately I can't solved it using the solution from there. For example if I execute this

```
echo 'start ';
var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir testtesttest'));
echo ' end';
```

I will get

> start NULL end

As you can see '/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop' is my complete path to Hadoop script. What is wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already get the solution. So basically my Hadoop can insert a directory without a prefix '/' but when I tried shell_exec directory name must be prefix by '/'. So just like the example above I need to add '/' before the directory name.

```
echo 'start ';
var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /testtesttest'));
echo ' end';
```

It will work. It apply to all hadoop command that need path directory.